# Copy data to same classes in different packages

Tags: java

I am calling an external service that returns the following class:

```
package abc;

public class FirstClass {
   private String name;
   private String age;
   private String number;
}
```

In my model, I have defined a class with same structure:

```
package xyz;

public class FirstClass {
   private String name;
   private String age;
   private String number;
}
```

I want to copy data from the `abc.FirstClass` object to `xyz.FirstClass` object. I don't want to map the data field by field. I think it can be done by dozer - are there any easier methods to do it?

Comment: you cant. it has to be field by field. but let me ask....why do you create two classes with same field? cant you merge both into a single file then have each class that needs the data to call that file?

Comment: Thanks - the class that I am copying from is in a jar that is provided by an external team. The java class that I am creating is part of my application's data model.

Comment: I saw it could done using dozer with xml , but look like here as well I need to specify source and destination fields in the xml. https://dzone.com/articles/bean-manipulation-using-dozer

Comment: yes , there are getters and setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [PropertyUtils#copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)):

> Copy property values from the "origin" bean to the "destination" bean for all cases where the property names are the same (even though the actual getter and setter methods might have been customized via `BeanInfo` classes).

Example:

```
abc.FirstClass src = new abc.FirstClass();
xyz.FirstClass dest = new xyz.FirstClass();
PropertyUtils.copyProperties(dest, src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java Reflection is the way to go.

#### From The Java™ Tutorials

> A field is a class, interface, or enum with an associated value. Methods in the java.lang.reflect.Field class can retrieve information about the field, such as its name, type, modifiers, and annotations. There are also methods which enable dynamic access and modification of the value of the field

Try something like this:

```
StackOverflow.abc.firstClass abc = new StackOverflow.abc.firstClass();
StackOverflow.xyz.firstClass xyz = new StackOverflow.xyz.firstClass();

Class<? extends StackOverflow.xyz.firstClass> xyzClass = xyz.getClass();
Field[] fields = abc.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field abcField : fields) {
    abcField.setAccessible(true); //To access private fields
    try {
        Field xyzField = xyzClass.getDeclaredField(abcField.getName());
        xyzField.setAccessible(true);
        xyzField.set(xyz, abcField.get(abc));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

You can check out this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) from Oracle for more details. Or, specifically this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/field.html) from the tutorial.

Comment: this would only enable the private fields to use but not copy the fields. he will still need to set each fields individually.
xyzField.set(xyz,abcField.get(abc))  <--- like this mapping... not copy entire class object. If he had to write all this then I think use spring bean would be better option.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot copy the entire class object is because each class object has unique hashcode. Even if your class has same attribute.

I know it is a pain but mapping by field is the only way to go. 
You can try use spring beans to help map the fields.

Comment: Thanks. How can spring beans help?

Comment: Simple way is just define bean in xml map each fields by name/type or whatever you need then autowire to your setter in your pojo class. when you need the fields just call the bean object. since the bean object is the same you can duplicate as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can using reflection

this does the job and shows it:

```
public class FirstClass {
       private String name;
       private String age;
       private String number;

       public FirstClass(String _name, String _age, String _number)
       {
           name=_name; age=_age; number=_number;
       }

    }


public class CloneClass {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String number;

       public CloneClass(String _name, String _age, String _number)
       {
           name=_name; age=_age; number=_number;
       }

       public void show()
       {
          System.out.println("NAME="+name+" AGE="+age+" NUMBER="+number);
       }

    }


    FirstClass A=new FirstClass("Jules","44","123A4535");

    CloneClass B=new CloneClass("","","");

    Class class1=A.getClass();
    Class class2=B.getClass();

    // all fields from A

    Field[] fields_A = class1.getDeclaredFields();
    Field[] fields_B = class2.getDeclaredFields();

    for (int k=0;k<fields_A.length;k++)
    {
        Field one_field=fields_A[k];

        // Name of field in source
        String name_of_field=one_field.getName();

        if (name_of_field.equals("this$0")) continue; // Not this !

        // Search if it exists in destination
        for (int z=0;z<fields_B.length;z++)
            {
            Field field_destination=fields_B[k];
            String name_of_field2=field_destination.getName();

            if (name_of_field.equals(name_of_field2))
            // TODO
            // You should also verify the type !
                {

                try
                {
                // To read private var
                one_field.setAccessible(true);
                field_destination.setAccessible(true);

                Object value=one_field.get( A);
                field_destination.set(B, value);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {System.err.println(ex);}
                }
                }
            } // for (int k=0;k<fields_A.length;k++)

    B.show();
```